# Address of an array changed despite using a pointer to navigation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-address, pointer-arithmetic

I want to better understand the pointer arithmetic. I know how to rewrite it with indexes but I want to understand where here a problem with pointers.

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    char **tmp;

    i=1;
    argv++;
    tmp = argv; // address of first element of array is:  e2b9f187
    printf("ptr: %x **ptr: %x\n", argv, &(**argv));
    printf("tmp: %x **tmp: %x\n", tmp, &(**tmp));
    while (--argc)
    {
        while(**tmp)
            (*tmp)++;
        printf("step %x ptr %x **ptr %x\n", i, argv, &(**argv));
        printf("step %x tmp %x **tmp %x\n", i, tmp, &(**tmp));
        i++;
        tmp++;
    } 
}
```

/* on the first iteration both addresses changed: `**tmp: e2b9f18b`, `**argv: e2b9f18b`, on the next iterations changes only `*tmp` positions.
My question is why despite using a pointer, the address of `**argv` changes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only copied `argv`, not `**argv`. Thus, you get 2 pointers to the same memory (`*argv` and `**argv`): if one pointer changes that memory address, the other pointer (looking at the same address), will also see that change.

Comment: If you remove one level of indirection (to make things a bit simpler), you can simply draw things on a piece of paper, with squares as memory addresses: you'd get to arrows (from your two pointers) to the same square.

Comment: @Evert. Thx, I understand the point. But here I don't use neither *argv nor **argv, so why they changing?

Comment: Then you didn't understand the point: you are changing the value pointed to by `**tmp`, which happens to be pointed to by `**argv` as well.

Comment: You (`argv`) point to a car (`**argv`) that is white (`&(**argv)`). You ask your friend to do the same (`tmp = argv`), that is, point to the same car (thus, `**tmp == **argv`); they also see the car being white (`&(**tmp)`). Now your friend paints the car in rainbow colours (`(*tmp)++` or similar), and the car colour seen by your friend (`&(**tmp)`) is literally all colours of the rainbow. You, as `argv`, are now also seeing the car in rainbow-colours (`&(**argv)`), not as white.

Comment: Note that printing pointers with `%x` is unreliable; it won't work properly with most 64-bit systems.  If you want to print pointers reliably, use either `%p` (and cast the pointers to `(void *)` first), or use `<inttypes.h>` and `PRIXPTR` (or `PRIxPTR`, or possibly but unusually `PRIuPTR` or `PRIoPTR`), and cast to `(uintptr_t)` first.  It looks like you're using a 32-bit system so you'll get away with, but beware — it is not reliable C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why despite using a pointer, the address of **argv changes.

To understand this, first, you need to understand the concept of the double pointer (pointer to pointer).

Lets consider one example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int X = 1; 
    int *ptr1, *ptr2;

    ptr1 = &X;
    ptr2 = ptr1;

    printf ("ptr1 : %p, ptr2 : %p\n", ptr1, ptr2);
    printf ("*ptr1 : %d, *ptr2 : %d\n", *ptr1, *ptr2);

    (*ptr1)++;
    printf ("ptr1 : %p, ptr2 : %p\n", ptr1, ptr2);
    printf ("*ptr1 : %d, *ptr2 : %d\n", *ptr1, *ptr2);

    return 0;
}
```

In the example, we are taking two pointers `ptr1` and `ptr2` and both are pointing to address of variable `X`.
The in-memory view will be something like:

```
                 +----------------+
            ptr1 | 0x7ffeeb1c4b48 |
                 +----------------+
                              |
                              |
                            X v
     +----------------+     +---+
ptr2 | 0x7ffeeb1c4b48 |---->| 1 |
     +----------------+     +---+
```

Any change you make in the value of `X` via `ptr1`, the changed value will be reflected when the value at the memory location of `X`  will be accessed via `ptr2` and vice versa.

```
The output of program is:
ptr1 : 0x7ffeeb1c4b48, ptr2 : 0x7ffeeb1c4b48
*ptr1 : 1, *ptr2 : 1
ptr1 : 0x7ffeeb1c4b48, ptr2 : 0x7ffeeb1c4b48
*ptr1 : 2, *ptr2 : 2
```

Now, let's modify the program and introduce the double pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int X = 1;
    int *ptr1;

    ptr1 = &X;
    printf ("ptr1 : %p\n", ptr1);

    int **ptr3, **ptr4;

    ptr3 = &ptr1;
    ptr4 = ptr3;

    printf ("ptr3 : %p, ptr4 : %p\n", ptr3, ptr4);
    printf ("*ptr3 : %p, *ptr4 : %p\n", *ptr3, *ptr4);
    printf ("**ptr3 : %d, **ptr4 : %d\n", **ptr3, **ptr4);

    (*ptr3)++;
    printf ("ptr1 : %p, *ptr1: %d\n", ptr1, *ptr1);
    printf ("ptr3 : %p, ptr4 : %p\n", ptr3, ptr4);
    printf ("*ptr3 : %p, *ptr4 : %p\n", *ptr3, *ptr4);
    printf ("**ptr3 : %d, **ptr4 : %d\n", **ptr3, **ptr4);

    return 0;
}
```

In the program, the statement:

```
(*ptr3)++;
```

will change the value (address) at `ptr1` which both `ptr3` and `ptr4` are pointing to. So, after this when you access the `*ptr4` or `**ptr4` the changed value will be reflected, similar as it was with single pointer `ptr2` in the first example.

The in-memory view now will be something like:

```
                           ptr1                       X
     +---------------+      +----------------+      +---+
ptr3 | 0x7ffeebc3fb40|----->| 0x7ffeebc3fb48 |----->| 1 |
     +---------------+      +----------------+      +---+
                                ^
                                |
                    +----------------+
               ptr4 | 0x7ffeebc3fb40 |
                    +----------------+
```

The program output is:

```
ptr1 : 0x7ffeeab5db48
ptr3 : 0x7ffeeab5db40, ptr4 : 0x7ffeeab5db40
*ptr3 : 0x7ffeeab5db48, *ptr4 : 0x7ffeeab5db48
**ptr3 : 1, **ptr4 : 1
ptr1 : 0x7ffeeab5db4c, *ptr1: 0      <=============== ptr1 now pointing to different mem location
ptr3 : 0x7ffeeab5db40, ptr4 : 0x7ffeeab5db40
*ptr3 : 0x7ffeeab5db4c, *ptr4 : 0x7ffeeab5db4c
**ptr3 : 0, **ptr4 : 0
```

Here, you can see that the address at which `ptr1` was pointing has been changed because of `(*ptr3)++`.

This is what happening in your program. In your program, you are doing:

```
        while(**tmp)
        (*tmp)++;
```

Which is changing the value at address that both `tmp` and `argv` pointing to.
And that's why, when you access the address of `&(**argv)` you are getting the different value as compared to initial value.

Also, in outer `while` loop, you are doing:

```
tmp++;
```

So, after the first iteration, the `tmp` and `argv` no more pointing to the same address.
And in further iterations you will get the different value of `&(**tmp)` but same value of `&(**argv)`.

Hope this helps.